# js assign one image input value to another

Tags: javascript, html, file

I have two image input fields

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="one" />
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="two" />
```

I am trying to sync value from `two` to `one`, whenever `two` receives input, assign the value to `one`. `two` is just a field visible in frontend, `one` is the original form used for data collection and upload.

```js
two.onchange = () => {one.value = two.value}
```

since it is file field, I wonder if this may not work (have not write unit test yet, because even the value is logged in fronted, I doubt the file will be catched in backend). I will be more than grateful if someone suggest a tangible way to do it.

Comment: Browsers don't allow you to set the value of an `<input type="file">`.  (Imagine a world where any website could specify a file path for a hidden file input and upload any file they want from your computer.)  As for a "way to do it", that really depends on what it is you're trying to do.  Why do you need two inputs to post the same value?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that for security reasons, javascript cannot change a file input field value

Comment: @David, I need two input file images, because the first one is in a form that extended from base template that is 'display noned' only used for uploading data, since js can assign input variables, we can write new forms independently in new template and assign data at last.

Comment: @Weilory Sir, I have answer your question. Please check my answer.

Comment: I think maybe I can only use one input and manipulate Dom, which when `two` is inputed, overwrite all attributes from `one` to `two`, and replace `one` by `two`, maybe this will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, @Abdul Basit's answer won't work. I tried to assign `files` but it turns out working in frontend, but there is actually no data transferred to backend. therefore, **it is impossible to assign value(files) between file inputs**.

```js
one.files = two.files
```

```py
<MultiValueDict: {}>
```

I did it by DOM replacement.

```js
// replace image input
two.remove();
Array.from(one.attributes).forEach(attr => {
    two.setAttribute(attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue);
});
one.parentNode.replaceChild(two, one);
```

```py
<MultiValueDict: {'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: main.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

here we got files in backend eventually.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing wrong you have to set `.files` property instead of `.value` because the Browser stored files in `files` property not in `value` property. You can do it like below Example:

```js
const one = document.getElementById('one');
const two = document.getElementById('two');
two.onchange = () => {one.files = two.files}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="one" />
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="two" />
```

Comment: thanks mate, temporarily accepted, I will let you know if it turns out working.

Comment: @Weilory Ok, Sir

Comment: sorry man it does not work